# How to remove the parent view, but keep its contents in the same place?

Tags: xcode, xcode6, uistoryboard, nslayoutconstraint, xcode-storyboard

In a project using auto layout I am editing a scene in the `Main.storyboard` file.

At the bottom there was a "Bottom View" with 2 custom buttons, but I have removed one button, so the container view become useless (here [fullscreen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3LLUT.png)):

[image: Xcode screenshot]

I wonder if there is any trick in Xcode 6 which would allow me to remove the "Bottom view", but keep its contents at the same place?

I have tried (numerous times) multiple select the contents ("Video ads button", "Video ads label", etc.) in the list at the left side of the above screenshot and to drag it outside the "Bottom view". This worked, but the position was lost and I couldn't really recreate it.